# Bind style class to column template?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table which is bound to a JSON model. Besides the content for the cell, the JSON model also contains a property that holds the class that should be applied to the template element of the column.

Is there a way to bind this property to the column template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the semantic color - see [JSB Bind TextViewColor](http://jsbin.com/socuf/1/edit)

```
{
  "lastName": "Guerrero",
  "name": "Hampton",
  "birthday":  1404172800000,
  "status" : "Critical"
 }

 oControl = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
   text: "{name}",
   semanticColor: "{status}"
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't bind anything to styleClass, but you can use factory function instead of template:

```
sap.ui.table.Column({
    factory : function(sId, oCtx){
        return new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
            text : oCtx.getProperty('Name')
        }).addStyleClass(oCtx.getProperty('SomeClass'))
    }
});
```

If you have model like this:

```
[{
    Name : 'John',
    SomeClass : 'Red'
}]
```

Comment: This actually looks very promissing since it gives a maximum of flexibility.
Unformtunatelly it does not work - at least not for me...
Do you use some additional library or custom elements?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: if the `DOC_ID` value is available, the cell should show a `Link` (based on the `DOC_ID`), otherwise just a text view.

I tried to specify a factory function to the `Column`. But as far as I could see, the factory function didn't even get called.

I did have success with the following approach:

- As template I specified a `HorizontalLayout`.
- As content of the layout, I specified both the `TextView` and the `Link`.
- To ensure that only one of the controls is visible, I did a property binding with formatter function on the `visible` attribute of each control.

With specifics removed, something like this:

```
new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "{i18n>FILE_NAME}"}),
    template: new sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout({
    // workaround for conditional control: 
    // if DOC_ID is not there, hide link; otherwise hide the text view
    content: [ 
        new sap.ui.commons.Link({
            text: "{FILENAME}",
            href: {
                path: "DOC_ID",
                formatter: function(value) {
                    return "http://www.example.com/" + value;
                }
            },
            visible: {
                path: "DOC_ID",
                formatter: function(value) {
                    return value != "";
                }
            }
        }),
        new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
            text: "{FILENAME}",
            visible: {
                path: "DOC_ID",
                formatter: function(value) {
                    return value == "";
                }
            }
        })
    ]
    }),
    sortProperty: "FILENAME",
    filterProperty: "FILENAME"
})
```

Depending on how many different controls you might have to render, this might also be a viable approach for you.